# Java Persistence Query Language JOIN

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have two tables :

```
A(bigint id, ...)
B(bigint id, varchar name, bigint id_A)
```

and now I want get all rows from A which exists in B (and those rows in B have name eg Andy)

Plase help me create dynamic query

class A

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A", schema = "mySchema")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
public class A{

    @Id
    private Long id;

}
```

class B

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "B",
    schema = "mySchema",
    uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
    "some_id", "id_A" }) })
public class B{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "Seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "Seq", sequenceName = "mySchema.mySeq")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_A", nullable = false)
    private A a;

    @Column(name = "id_A", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Long IdA;
}
```

Comment: JPQL works in terms of object model, not the database schema. You need to show your classes rather than the schema.

Comment: no you didn't. you posted an awful mess, I tried to fix it for you

Answer (score 0):

There are several weird parts. e.g. this:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_A", nullable = false)
private A a;

@Column(name = "id_A", updatable = false, insertable = false)
private Long IdA;
```

With the `@JoinColumn` annotation you are telling the JPA provider that it should use the specified column for internal mapping, but with the IdA field, you are trying to manage the column yourself. Which is it going to be?

Comment: I don't know what more You need. I also dont know how to explain You how this work, but it's work :)